# An English to English glossary with one line word meanings

Tags: plaintext, glossaries

I'm working on a dictionary that gets english words and returns their meanings. My duty is to write a program that reads words and their meanings form a base-input glossary file that is a text file then implements B-Tree Data-Structure for saving datas on hard disk and for future runs, just references to the B-Tree file and resolves given words meanings.

I googled for this but got nothing!

I wrote the BTree DS itself but now I need a text file (or any parsable text format like xml, json etc. ) to complete program. Cause I just can use Java and/or C/C++ and I just need to a glossary file that have many enough word/meaning pair (about 10000 word) please just offer glossary files and pay attention I caen not use any kind of database library so I can't use sql files out there! :(

Also I don't want to use non-free resources or files! ;)

Comment: Look here, and see what you can find - http://www.dicts.info/dictionaries.php

Comment: Is it strictly need to be stored in plain files? May be you can use a lightweight NoSQL (which you can embed in your application). All of this using Java or C++ driver.

Comment: @StephenC : I love them! No-SQL Databases! but the project headmaster want it! :||

Answer (score 0):

Information on downloading dumps of Wiktionary is at: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#Downloading_Wiktionary

It's free but you should still pay attention to the licensing terms.

The dumps are available as XML.

More generally, in response to your comment about SQL:

- "Cannot use any kind of database library" sounds like a completely arbitrary restriction. There are many free, light SQL databases you could embed in your application. [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) is an example.
- If you really don't want to use SQL in your application, you can still very trivially write a program to extract data from an SQL database and convert it into whatever format your app requires.

Comment: (although my guess is that the arbitrary restriction is evidence of a homework assignment)

Comment: The "cannot use" comment is probably code for "don't want to learn how to use" :-).  Either way, there is no reason that he cannot use SQL to extract a database to a text file for use by his program.

Comment: @StephenC : I know how to use them but the project details restricts me to do so! but I personally prefer to use a SQL system because it's so fast and convenient! ;)